# which remote_path should i type in for SFTP Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sftp, sublimetext3, remote-server

I am trying to configure `SFTP Sublime Text 3` on my remote server.

So I set the

- IP
- username
- password

But I don't know what the right **remote_path** is ?

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: The path on the server where your files are located maybe …?

Comment: yes i have already typed the path of the file on the server  "/var/www/trunk/project_name/" but it does not want to connect. I got this massage "failure (Connection timeout)"

Answer (score 0):

Remote Path is the default folder you land in if you choose Browse Server.

If you're logging in as a user and working out of that directory the Remote Path would be `/home/<username>/project_folder`

It seems you have it configured correctly for your purposes however, it shouldn't interfere with your login attempt. For me it defaults to the home directory if unable to reach the intended directory.

Comment: Be sure to add a slash `/ ` at the end of the path. In my case, not adding it resulted in a "void" folder download: nothing was being downloaded, and the status bar in the sublime console continued to print out dots forever, whereas nothing was being added to the SFTP debug log.